# Why is Swing taking such a long time to create this panel?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, swingx

I'm currently writing a part of my program that inserts a dynamic amount of JComboBoxes into the JPanel, however I'm noticing that it's incredibly slow (takes ~10 seconds to finish), and it freezes the entire Swing thread to do it. I'm not sure what better solution there is to this, but I know there is a better way.

```
private JPanel createInventoryPanel(PlayerInventory inventory)
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug"));

    int columns = 4;
    int rows = inventory.getSize() / 4;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            GameItem item = inventory.getItems().get(index);

            JComboBox box = new JComboBox(itemNames);
            box.setEditable(true);
            AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(box);
            box.setSelectedItem(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(item.getName()) + " (0x" + HexUtil.shortToHexString(item.getValue()) + ")");

            boolean shouldWrap = ((index + 1) % 4 == 0) && index != 0;

            panel.add(box, "" + (shouldWrap ? "wrap" : ""));
            itemBoxes.add(box);

            index++;
        }
    }

    return panel;
}
```

So to explain my code:

I have a JFrame, and a JTabbed pane. In the tabbed pane, I'm creating this 'inventory panel' to fit in it. In the inventory panel, there is a 'grid' (rows & columns) of JComboBoxes, where the amount is the size of the inventory. Each combobox is autocompleteable (when typing) for easy use.

So I create the Jpanel, set it to a MigLayout (using debug for visual debugging).

There are 4 columns (I chose this number)
And the amount of rows depend on the size of the inventory divided by the 4 columns. Simple stuff.

Then of course I use a for-loop inside a for-loop to allow me to create my XY grid of jcomboboxes. This is where it gets really slow. I'm not sure if the looping is slow (which I doubt, since it's simple arithmetic) or if there's a threading issue or what..

WordUtils is a part of Apache's Commons-Lang library, and AutoCompleteDecorator is used for the JComboBoxes to autocomplete via the SwingX library.

GameItem is simply an object to represent the game item, with a few small values in it (shorts, bytes, etc.. nothing concerning there).

I'm stumped on how to make this faster.

Comment: any profiler will tell you more than our assumptions

Comment: [This answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27187624/3676217) could probably be your problem. It's with the JTabbedPane and MigLayout.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker The problem is that so many swing objects are being rendered, it's very slow...but I don't know another way to do this.

Comment: @lschuetze I saw that, unfortunately it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you are creating too much stuff at the same time. And I think `JComboBox` is a very complex thing to render.

However, this cannot be done on another thread because you are creating UI components, which must be done on the UI thread (main thread).

I encountered this situation too. But that was when I was creating Windows Forms apps, which is a completely different technology. But I think the basic idea is the same.

I wanted to add 100 UI components to a `Panel` (which is like a `JPanel`). And it took a long long time. So I decided to show another `Panel` on top to cover the `Panel` (the one that I was adding stuff to). Then I put a label on the cover panel that says "Loading". This way, people will know that it is loading and will not freak out. Of course, after generating the components I hid the cover panel

Surprisingly, when I run the program, the cover panel appears just for a brief moment! After it disappeared, I see that all the things I wanted to generate had already been generated!

So I drew a conclusion, **UI components will appear faster if it doesn't need to be rendered.**

You should probably do something like that. Place a `JPanel` on top of the other one while you are generating the combo boxes. When you finish, hide the panel again, or remove it completely.

Comment: Use `CardLayout` to change views.

Answer (score 2):

> it's incredibly slow (takes ~10 seconds to finish)

First measure the execution times. One simple way to measure execution time is to use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). Change your code to something like this:

```
 long start = System.nanoTime();
 try {
    // The code you want to measure
 } finally {
      long end = System.nanoTime();
      long execTime = end - start;
      System.out.println("Execution of .... took " + execTime + "ns";
 }
```

...or you use a profiler. You can use [`jvisualvm`'s profiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html). `jvisualvm` is usually located in `JDK_HOME/bin`.

Comment: I know what takes the longest, but I don't know how to make it faster.. Profiling will tell me nothing other than it's slow. I can see that the problem is painting so many components, yet I have no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the problem isn't specifically a rendering issue, but rather than the JComboBox takes a ridiculous toll on entry sizes over a certain amount. I was entering around 4,700 items to more than 50 boxes, so it really took a performance hit.

Unfortunately, as much as I'd love to use the JComboBox , I'll be switching to a JTextField ..

Comment: Then [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2075329?start=0&tstart=0) will give you the ability to add all items at once.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use autocompletedecorator. instead use this [Example: Adding Autocomplete to JTextField](http://stackabuse.com/example-adding-autocomplete-to-jtextfield/)